# Show popup only once Jquery, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, session-cookies

I have a popup which opens on click of a button. The button is present in all the pages.

The popup should appear only once.

When a user opens a page and click on button the popup must appear and if he clicks on the same button again popup should not come, and from that page if he redirects to another page and clicks on the same button popup should not appear.

If the browser is closed and opened again the popup must appear and the same conditions must apply again.

These are the cases when a popup should appear and when it should not.

How to achieve this with jquery and PHP

Comment: Look into cookies. https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: You can achieve this using javascript session storage. no need to use PHP.

Comment: Using session storage you can achieve this.

Comment: @guradio I am trying to create a session on click of button, and showing the popup based on session variable, but on browser close the session is not getting cleared and popup is not coming

Comment: @spankajd could you give an example

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen could you give an example because I tried using cookie and session but the cookie is not getting cleared when browser is closed

Comment: put your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can create popup show only once on click using **sessionStorage** in jquery- check working
>   example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayatullahrahmani/p1p2zpx5/)

[jsfiddle.net/ayatullahrahmani/p1p2zpx5/](https://jsfiddle.net/ayatullahrahmani/p1p2zpx5/)

**here is jquery Code-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               $(".open").click(function () {
                    $(".animateDivWrap").addClass("activePopup");
               });

              $(".close").click(function () {
                  $(".animateDivWrap").removeClass("activePopup");

                  sessionStorage.setItem("myClass", "firstGone");
                    $(".animateDivWrap").addClass(sessionStorage.myClass);
              });

              // after first load this class would be added
              $(".animateDivWrap").addClass(sessionStorage.myClass);
          });
```

**css-**

```
 body {
         overflow:hidden;
         }
         .animateDivWrap {
         position: absolute;
         top: 70px;
         right: 0px;
         left:0px;
         width: 300px;
         height: 199px;
         background: #f6f6f6;
         z-index: 9;
         display: none; 
         /*opacity: 0;*/
         border: solid 1px #ddd;
         border-radius: 5px;
             margin:auto;
         }
         .animateDivContent {
         position:relative;
             padding: 10px;
         }
         .animateDivContent .close {
         position: absolute;
         right: 5px;
         top: 3px;
         font-size: 12px;
         color: #373434;
         opacity: 1;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp { 
         0% { 
         opacity: 0; 
         -webkit-transform: translateY(400px); 
         } 
         50%{
         opacity: 0.3; 
         }
         100% { 
         opacity: 1; 
         -webkit-transform: translateY(0); 
         } 
         } 
         @keyframes fadeInUp { 
         0% { 
         opacity: 0; 
         transform: translateY(400px); 
         } 
         50%{
         opacity: 0.3; 
         }
         100% { 
         opacity: 1; 
         transform: translateY(0); 
         } 
         } 
         .fadeInUp{ 
         opacity: 0; 
         -webkit-transform: translateY(400px); 
         transform: translateY(400px);
         }
         .activePopup {
         display: block;
         /*opacity:1;*/
         /*-webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;*/
         -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp; 
         animation-name: fadeInUp; 
         -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
         animation-name: fadeInUp;
         animation-duration: 1s;
         }
         .close {
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         .firstGone  {
         display:none;
         }
```

**html-**

```
<button type="button" class="open">open</button>

      <div class="animateDivWrap">
         <div class="animateDivContent">
            <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)" title="close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**sessionStorage** is the best option for this. as it stores data for that session only. So you can store whether the popup is opene or not.

Just bind the following function as handler function on button click.

```
function onButtonClick(e)
{
    if (sessionStorage.isButtonClicked == undefined) {

         sessionStorage.isButtonClicked = true;

         // You can do require functionality here e.g. open the popup. 

    } else {

         // do nothing as popup is already opened.
    }
}
```